# JavaScript analog of java.lang.Optional?

Tags: javascript, java, null, undefined, option-type

I'm looking for a client-side JavaScript library that would let me write code similar to what I can do in other languages using some flavour of Option type, for example [java.lang.Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

My target is to avoid `null`/`undefined` checks in client code and make API more explicit.

Here is the API I want to be able to write:

```
var dictionary = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2'
}

function getValue(key){
    var value = dictionary[key];
    if(value !== null && value !== undefined) 
         return Optional.of(value);
    else 
         return Optional.empty();
}
```

And here is the client code:

```
var value = getValue('key3');
if(value.isPresent())
     console.log('got a value: ' + value.get().toUpperCase());
else
     console.log('no value found!');
```

Or sometimes:

```
var value = getValue('unknown key').orElse('default value');
```

If I call `get()` on `Optional.empty()` value, it should throw some kind of `Error`.
If I call `Optional.of()` on `null` or `undefined`, it should throw as well.

Comment: I feel like options, though sensible, are not really the kind of thing that the Javascript "community" is into. [Purescript, on the other hand...](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-maybe)

Answer (score 6):

Writing an Optional implementation yourself shouldn't be that hard, given the [java.lang.Optional source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Optional.java).

Although you have to take some differences into consideration, i.e.Javascript distinguishes between `undefined` and `null`, you have no such concept as Generics and the Java implementation of map is considered by some as [broken](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/08/optional-broken/). Nevertheless it's fairly easy to implement.

However, I've done an implementation ([optional.js](https://github.com/devcon5io/awtt/blob/master/javascript/src/main/javascript/optional.js)) myself, which suits my needs and you may use it if you like, but it probably doesn't satisfy all your requirements (i.e. `of()` does not throw an exception on undefined or null, but `get()` does)

With my code, your example would be like

```
function getValue(key){
    return Optional.of(dictionary[key]);
}

var value = getValue('key3');
value.ifPresent(function() {
     console.log('got a value: ' + value.get().toUpperCase());
 });
```

Btw. code like this

```
if(value.isPresent())
     console.log('got a value: ' + value.get().toUpperCase());
else
     console.log('no value found!');
```

is no valid use case for Optional as you could easily replace it will null/undefined checks. But if you require methods like `filter`, `map`, `flatMap` and `ifPresent`, you'll benefit much more for from it.

Answer (score 5):

> For those who still interested in this in 2021.

### tl;dr:

- use the ES [Optional chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#syntax) always. It's more semantic and artistic in the JavaScript way (Maybe with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining)). like:

  ```
  obj.val?.prop || defaultValue
  obj.val?.[expr]
  obj.arr?.[index]
  obj.func?.(args)
  ```
- Using the `Optional` class it's may be **NOT** supported by other packages in TypeScript and if you just want to deeply access an object property is **NOT** kind of easy.

### for more info:

I try to make a roughly `Optional` class with TypeScript:

```js
import isNil from "../is/isNil";
// isNil = val => val === null || val === undefined

class Optional<T> {
  value = null;
  constructor(value: T) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  static EMPTY = new Optional(null);

  static empty(): Optional<unknown> {
    return Optional.EMPTY;
  }

  static of<U>(value: U): Optional<U> {
    return new Optional(value);
  }

  isPresent(): boolean {
    return !isNil(this.value);
  }

  filter<T>(predicate: (value: T) => Boolean): Optional<T> {
    if (!this.isPresent()) {
      return this;
    }
    return predicate(this.value) ? this : Optional.EMPTY;
  }

  map<T, U>(mapper: (value: T) => U): Optional<U> {
    if (!this.isPresent()) {
      return this;
    }
    return Optional.of(mapper(this.value));
  }

  flatMap<T, U>(mapper: (value: T) => Optional<U>): Optional<U> {
    if (!this.isPresent()) {
      return this;
    }
    const mapped = mapper(this.value);
    if (isNil(mapped)) {
      throw new Error("flatMap will map the value not to null or undefined.");
    }
    return mapped;
  }

  orElse<T>(other: T): T {
    return isNil(this.value) ? other : this.value;
  }
}
```

Here you can see when I want to access property by using Optional, it will write like below:

```
Optional.of(dictionary)
.map((obj)=> {
  const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj)
  // ⚠️ when you use like this, it may also cause an error.
  return descriptors.key1.value
})
.orElse('defaultValue')
```

And Using `Optional chain` will like this:

```
dictionary?.key1 || 'defaultValue'
```

Comment: I recommend the typescript-optional package: https://github.com/bromne/typescript-optional

Answer (score 1):

For some usage scenarios, an array with zero to one elements is a pretty good fit.

It is simple, has concise syntax for creation and querying, and also gives you builtin filter() and map(), which are among my main reasons for using Optional:

```
    const one = ["foo"];
    const none = [];

    console.log("one.isPresent: " + !!one.length);
    console.log("none.isPresent: " + !!none.length);

    console.log("one.get: " + one[0]);

    // Caveat: this 'orElse' will fail for values that are present but falsy:
    console.log("one.orElse('fallback'): " + (one[0] || 'fallback') );
    console.log("none.orElse('fallback'): " + (none[0] || 'fallback'));

    console.log("Fluent chaining: "+ (
        none
            .filter(s => s.length > 2)
            .map(lodash.upperCase)
        [0] || "too short"
    ));
```

If you are willing to modify the prototype you could add a more robust orElse, and syntactic sugar as desired.