# Generic TypeScript function that only accepts e.g. `number|undefined` and never just `number`

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a utility class to throw an exception when something could be undefined like `throwIfUndefined(array[index]).function()` and `throwIfUndefined(obj.key).function()`. This is to make my code more concise as using e.g. if conditions and throwing manually is very verbose.

I tried this attempt:

```
export const throwIfUndefined = <T>(v: T | undefined): T => {
  if (v === undefined) {
    throw new Error("Unexpected undefined");
  } else {
    return v;
  }
};
```

This mostly works:

```
const x = Math.random() < 0.5 ? undefined : 1;
throwIfUndefined(x); // works: type-checks as expected
throwIfUndefined(1); // broken: should give type error because the input can never be undefined
```

How do I fix the last case so TypeScript will catch when I use `throwIfUndefined` unnecessarily?

I tried using conditional types but I can't get my head around how they would work here.

Edit: Example of the kind of code I don't like having to write

```
const item = array[index];
if (!item) return;

return item.function() ? 1 : 2;
```

This gets worse the more array items you have to fetch. I'd rather have a shorthand like this (avoid the extra condition and the extra variable):

```
return throwIfUndefined(array[index]).function() ? 1 : 2
```

Comment: It seems like you're trying to write something like Java's Optional, in which case see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32325726/3001761 or use https://github.com/bromne/typescript-optional

Comment: This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because "*This is to make my code more concise as using e.g. if conditions and throwing manually is very verbose.*" is already the wrong approach. If you type your code correctly, you should have very few if any `undefined`s available. And those can often be handled without needing to throw hard errors anyway.

Comment: Unsure what you're trying to accomplish, and why the type checker isn't good enough for it https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCigLkWEAWwCMUAnASkQG8BYAKEUTJShDKSgG4GBfBhhAQZEAD0QBeRAFkAhlAAWAOjKywAEziFMVADyIADEoCsiAPyJw6lMBhgU6xHgCMPeg1QZMoilyA

Comment: @VLAZ Added an example. You can't eliminate all checks like these when you're fetching arbitrary keys.

Comment: @bellsdid fetching "arbitrary keys" *is the problem*. It's sort of like trying to throw your pizza out of the window because it doesn't have mushrooms. When you didn't order one with mushrooms in the first place. The action is 1. too drastic 2. too late. If you are working with well-defined data, then you eliminate a lot of the arbitrariness. The fact that `obj` doesn't have `key` isn't an issue at the time you try to access `key`. The core of the issue an apparently invalid case because `obj` *must* have `key` yet doesn't.

Comment: @VLAZ How would you rewrite my example at the bottom then where the array index is coming from the user typing it in so you're not sure it's a valid index yet?

Comment: @bellsdid you're still posing the wrong question. Why *would* the user be typing in an array index? And why would they be allowed to type in something invalid? Even if that happens, why should that be an error? A `arr[index] ?? ""` might be all that's needed (assuming it's an array of strings). Or maybe `arr[clamp(0, arr.length-1, index)]` to keep the selection within bounds if that makes more sense. Stop asking about handling things that should have been handled several steps back. Instead think of how to avoid any of that. Seems like there should have been validation for user input, at least

Comment: @VLAZ  Yes, I know about fallback values and clamping, but this won't work when you can't give a reasonable fallback value: `(arr[index] ?? "").function()`. This code could literally be in the user input validation function where it's checking `documents[userChosenDocumentId].userHasAccess()` is true for it to be a valid user choice or not. You've really got no code anywhere that throws on undefined and then calls a function via that value otherwise? Sometimes you just get lumped with code that hasn't done the checks (library code, network data) so pushing idealistic code isn't helpful.

Comment: @bellsdid Validate on entry in the system. Reject invalid values as soon as possible. Now you don't need to try and validate seven steps after the system boundary. You're just ignoring anything I say to try and claim it's impossible. Yes. `(arr[index] ?? "").function()` won't work *because that's evidently not an array of strings*. I already had a disclaimer for that. If a string is not a valid fallback, then you can figure out a valid one. Or use an Optional as already suggested. You're still trying to tell me that you have to handle derailed trains instead of trying to not have them derail.

Comment: @VLAZ In Vue, I can create HTML like `<div ref="elSelected">` to bind an HTML element to the variable `elSelected:Element|undefined` whenever that element exists (it might not if nothing is selected yet). If later I want to do `elSelected.focus()` to move the keyboard focus there, I have to check if `elSelected` is undefined first. A fallback value just isn't helpful here. I want to fail fast and throw an exception. Your analogies aren't enlightening. I know languages like Haskell and how to leverage types but it's much harder to avoid undefined in JavaScript, especially with UI/DOM stuff.

Comment: @bellsdid 1. `elSelected?.focus()` is there 2. throwing an error because the user didn't follow meticulous steps for how the UI should be used (first focus this thing, *then* click there) sounds like even more XY. Users can click anywhere. That's not an error condition. You can constrain their choices with forms, wizards, layouts, etc. Maybe I'm not enlightening you but you keep coming up with examples that are either not real problems or are only completely fictitious problems that in the real world shouldn't be.

Comment: @VLAZ `try { if (!elSelected) {throw Error();} elSelected.focus(); /* 10 more lines for this UI action like starting an animation, updating the undo stack, updating stats */ } catch { window.alert("unexpected error. try again") }`. `elSelected?.focus()` isn't helpful. If `elSelected` is undefined, I know something unexpected is going on and want to bail instead of polluting my happy path code with error checks. Yes, I disable this UI action when it shouldn't work but the unexpected undefined is still possible if I have bugs like the Vue binding not working (common!). You never use exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that it's a great idea, but one approach you can take is to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) the generic type so that `undefined` needs to be assignable to it.  This would be a *lower bound* constraint, like saying `T super undefined` instead of `T extends ⋯`, but TypeScript doesn't natively support lower bound constraints (there is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520)).  You can simulate it by writing a recursive constraint of the following form:

```
export const throwIfUndefined =
  <T extends (undefined extends T ? unknown : never)>(v: T) => {
    if (v === undefined) {
      throw new Error("Unexpected undefined");
    } else {
      return v;
    }
  };
```

Here `T` is the type of `v`, and the return type of the function is `T & ({} | null)`.  The type `{} | null` is essentially "everything except `undefined`", so `T & ({} | null)` is essentially "`T` except with `undefined` removed".  Let's test it out:

```
const x = Math.random() < 0.5 ? undefined : 1;
const y = throwIfUndefined(x); // okay;
y // 1

throwIfUndefined(1); // error
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

For the good call, the input is of type `1 | undefined` and the output is of type `1`.  For the bad call, the compiler complains that `number` is not assignable to `never`.  This is possibly a bit of a confusing error, but there's not much better to be done without *invalid types* or *throw types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#23689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689).  If you use this approach you'll probably want to document the function well enough to let people know what's going on.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/LAKFFMA8AcHsCcAuACAxrAdgZxYgFvLAO4CSAZgKoYAm4ZAlhuNcgLyjLIA8AKslInA0syABQBXGnUbN+kQcOR8A-MkkBrDMQzIAXMiYA3cPACUAPlGH9PU23PIA3h07J6ZMYbatWaqQyZqO2cQV1d8QiIDcCiAUXhCeFEAIiooaHBUQRZJWgDmZNMAbhdOAF9+ABsscCdS13hwRHF4HUMS0NcylzKO0FB0bBRINmQAWQBDfAA6eAmaWABbUTsuZAAGaYBWZFVc6UC9ZABGDsGcZABPUYjicio8mWpRSGLkAHp35Fh1CcuO66fE79EC3UiUfxPUTHN5AkyJUBAgCC8AA5uJFkIULAPIhLhlkAByDAYgBGJkJbhEWhQEywWHoqIwE1JlVqiFgyGgEzmmME8G+uPxtWJ4GM8EJ0xBQA)

Comment: @jaclz Thanks! You anticipated all my follow up questions too, like how to make the error message better. :) Curious what you mean by "I don't know that it's a great idea" and what you'd prefer instead.